# Converting a String to an Integer

Tags: java, string, integer, int

I'm trying to convert a String to an Integer. I have the following code:

```
List<String> strings = populateSomeStrings();
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
    ints.add(Integer.valueOf(strings.get(i)));
}
```

When I run it I get an exception saying:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1000"
```

Any ideas why this would be happening? I also tried Integer.parseInt but it does the same thing.

Thanks

Comment: Why use `Integer`? Have you tried using the primitive `int`?

Comment: Try printing out the unicode values of the characters in the troublesome strings.  You might have something unexpected in there.

Comment: second that. list out the contents of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's obviously something in your strings that isn't numeric.

Catch the exception and print out the string length and code points for each character, using `codePointAt` for example.

That should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Shot. I fixed it by adding a strings.get(i).trim().